# merge dataframes on index in for loop

Tags: python, pandas

I am having a lot of trouble merging these dataframes on the same index which are all in the same for loop. Below when I print my code I will get two dataframes under the for loop, I want to do sometype of `dataframe.merge()` where I can get it to look like this.

```
# price1 when printed in the for loop  

             Close   tic
Date                    
2010-05-27   31.33  AAPL
2010-05-28   31.77  AAPL
...            ...   ...
2020-05-22  318.89  AAPL
2020-05-26  316.73  AAPL

[2516 rows x 2 columns]

             Close   tic
Date                    
2010-05-27   38.54  TROW
2010-05-28   37.08  TROW
...            ...   ...
2020-05-22  115.09  TROW
2020-05-26  120.05  TROW

[2516 rows x 2 columns]
```

Next is what I want it to look like where they would be merged on the index. Where the new columns are the new dataframe.

```
#what I want it to look like
             Close   tic  Close   tic
Date                    
2010-05-27   31.33  AAPL  38.54  TROW
2010-05-28   31.77  AAPL  37.08  TROW
...            ...   ...
2020-05-22  318.89  AAPL  115.09  TROW
2020-05-26  316.73  AAPL  120.05  TROW

[2516 rows x 4 columns]
```

My code below is.

```
import yfinance as yf
import pandas as pd
import csv

def price(ticker):
    company = yf.Ticker(ticker)
    price = company.history(period="10y")
    price_df = pd.DataFrame(price)
    price_df.drop(price_df.columns[[0,1,2,4,5,6]], axis = 1, inplace = True)
    price_df['tic'] = (ticker)
    return price_df

l = ["AAPL", "TROW"]
for ticker in l:
    price1 = price(ticker) 
    print(price1)
```

Thx in advance

Comment: should it be `pd.concat((df1,df2), axis=1)`?

Comment: Use pd.merge and join on Date column for both left and right data frames. You need either inner, left outer, right outer or outer join depending on your logic for merging the data frames when Date in one dataframe exists but in the other does not. Please be more specific with 5 lines of dummy data and showing 5 lines of expected output. Also, consider edge cases if any.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your "date" column is the dataframe index

```
df1.set_index('date')
df2.set_index('date')
```

then merge two frames

```
df_merged = pd.concat((df1,df2) , axis =1)
```

Answer (score 0):

According to your sample data, simply

```
price1 = price('AAPL').join(price('TROW'))
print(price1)
```

may work fine.

In more complicated cases, comments from CypherX could be considered.